# How do resident foreign currency accounts in India work?

Tags: india, bank-account, inr-indian-rupee, foreign-currency

I live in India, and I'm considering opening a resident foreign currency account, to receive dollars from outside India.

Is the balance (in dollars, say) automatically converted to rupees when I try to:

- Transfer money to someone using IMPS, RTGS or NEFT?
- Use a debit card to pay in rupees at a shop?
- Use an ATM card to withdraw rupees at an Indian ATM?
- Write a rupee-denominated cheque?
- Have a biller withdraw rupees from my account using ECS?

In other words, can I pretend that a resident foreign currency account is a rupee account when I want to withdraw rupees? Or are there restrictions on what rupee transactions I can perform on a resident foreign currency account that don't exist on a rupee-denominated savings account?

Am I correct in understanding that a resident foreign currency account cannot have deposits made into it in rupees, say if someone wants to transfer money to me using IMPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the balance (in dollars, say) automatically converted to rupees when I try to:

You can't transact on this account like you do on savings account. So there is NO ATM/Debit Card/Net Banking. You have to walk-in to the Branch and withdraw in local currency or in travel cards as required.

> Am I correct in understanding that a resident foreign currency account cannot have deposits made into it in rupees, say if someone wants to transfer money to me using IMPS?

Deposits are restricted. [See RBI circular](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/ECMUserView.aspx?Id=52&CatID=10)

Comment: isn't it also true that the forex can only be held for 30 days from the date of deposit and one has to convert to INR within this period?

Comment: @ottodidakt Yes. If you have Cash in Fx beyond USD 250; this needs to be converted into INR with 30 days. If you have some reason, say a travel planned immediately, you can hold it longer. However the RFC account works differently. You can hold the Fx as long as you desire.